# Collision Detection In JavaScript - A Unusual Bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, collision

I am trying to detect collision detection in JavaScript on my game (It's a phone game) , but I can't think how to!

In my JavaScript there was a circle with an id of "playercircle", and i wnat to know how to collide it to other elements (coin, enemy, ex).

Here is one of the tries for the coin. But first check all my code:

```
if (playercircle.style.left == coin.style.left && playercircle.style.left == coin.style.left) {
    score++;
}
```

So here's my code:

```js
var score = 0;

const coin = document.querySelector(".coin");
    coin.style.top = Math.random()*130 + "px";

const enemy = document.querySelector(".enemy")
    enemy.style.top = Math.random()*100 + "px";

let playercircle=document.querySelector(".playercircle");
function moveLeft() {
    let left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(playercircle).getPropertyValue("left"));
left -= 10;
playercircle.style.left = left + "px";
}
function moveUp() {
    let top = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(playercircle).getPropertyValue("top"));
top -= 10;
playercircle.style.top = top + "px";
}
function moveRight() {
    let left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(playercircle).getPropertyValue("left"));
left += 10;
playercircle.style.left = left + "px";
}
function moveDown() {
    let top = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(playercircle).getPropertyValue("top"));
top += 10;
playercircle.style.top = top + "px";
}

if (playercircle.style.left == coin.style.left && playercircle.style.top == coin.style.top) {
    score = score + 1;
    alert(score)
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#game {
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.playercircle {
    height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: darkblue;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
top: 130px;
left: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.coin {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.enemy {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    animation: enemy 3s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes enemy {
    0%{top: 230px;}
    50%{top: -120px;}
    100%{top: 230px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Circle Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn-up"onclick="moveUp()">UP</button>
    <button id="btn-down"onclick="moveDown()">DOWN</button>
    <button id="btn-left"onclick="moveLeft()">LEFT</button>
    <button id="btn-right"onclick="moveRight()">RIGHT</button>
    <div id="game">
    <div class="playercircle"></div>
    <div class="coin"></div>
    <div class="enemy"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you run it instead of keyboard controls it uses button controls because it's a code bit on [SoloLearn](https://www.sololearn.com), a code tool for Android/IOS phones (and also computers).

Answer (score 0):

Create an if conditional that specifies if enemy "px" is congruent to playercircle px. Ditto for coins. You might have to set up a function for "px" zones that act as collision modules.